# PDO statement both with IN and LIKE operator

Tags: php, pdo

```
        $in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($folioIds), '?'));

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM page WHERE folio_id IN(". $in .") AND content LIKE ?");

        foreach ($folioIds as $k => $id) {
            $statement->bindValue($k+1, $id);
        }
        $statement->bindValue($k+1, "%" . $q . "%");

        if($statement->execute()) {
            print_r($statement->fetchAll());
            $statement->debugDumpParams();
        }
```

I'm trying to use both In and Like operator in a query, and it's throwing invalid number of tokens error.

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'
```

Also could we use both named and ? parameters, my attempt using that failed as well.

Comment: Is `$folioIds` indexed sequentially from 0 (PDO parameters are indexed from 1)? Perhaps better to define `$k` independently of that array's keys and explicitly increment on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$k` is undefined outside the `foreach` loop

It's probably easier like this:

```
 $statement = $this->connection->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM page WHERE folio_id IN(". $in .") AND content LIKE ?");
 $values=$folioIds;
 $values[]="%" . $q . "%";
 if ($statement->execute($values)){
    $rows=$statement->fetchAll();
 }
```

Comment: cleaner approach, but $k was still available outside the for loop, I echoed, I wonder if there was another issue

Comment: hmmm, not sure, I find passing the values (as array) into execute easier than binding in this type of query

Comment: me too, but I had no option to use that because of IN operator

Comment: it should still work, it will look like `"IN(?,?,?) and content like ?"` and values=`[1,2,3,%foobar%]`

Comment: yes it worked but wonder why $k+1 gave the problem outside the loop, it was still accessible (echoed)

Comment: still not sure, I'll let you know if i figure it out